# Parsing Json Numerical Values In Java

Tags: java, json, parsing, classcastexception, json-simple

My Java program takes a JSON string as an argument and parses it. I am using json-simple parser. Here is the [link](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) to it. I am trying to pass the following JSON string as an argument to the program.

```
{
  "obj":"timeout" , 
  "valInMs":15000
}
```

I am trying to get the value for "valInMs" . Following is the java code that is doing this

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObj;
jsonObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonString);
Integer timeout = (Integer) paramJson.get("valInMs");
```

**The above code raises `java.lang.ClassCastException`: `java.lang.Long` cannot be cast to `java.lang.Integer` .**

**I am trying to understand what should the program be expecting when it comes across a JSON numberic value.** One cannot determine the "type" by looking at the JSON object.

**How should a java program be handling this ?**

Form [json.org](http://www.json.org/) it seems like a Json "value" (out of many other things that it can be) can be "number" . A "number" can be one of the following:

```
number
 - int
 - int frac
 - int exp
 - int frac exp
```

Comment: It is quite unfortunate that JSON-Simple (apparently) lacks any sort of rigorous documentation.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I think you can use
**int timeout = Integer.parseInt(paramJson.get("valInMs").toString());**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Number timeoutNum = (Number) paramJson.get("valInMs");
Long timeoutLong = null;
Double timeoutDouble = null;
if (timeoutNum instanceof Long) {
    timeoutLong = (Long) timeoutNum;
}
else if (timeoutNum instanceof Double) {
    timeoutDouble = (Double) timeoutNum;
}
else { ... punt ... }
```

Or one can use `intValue()` et al on `timeoutNum`, if necessary coercing between integer and float.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This works for me

if (jobj.get("valInMs") != null)
{
    Number val = (Number) jobj.get("valInMs");
    int valInMs = val.intValue();
}
else
    valInMs = 0;
```